# How do you finish a valve when using pex pipes

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, pex

I'm doing all of my work with expansion PEX. I'm a little puzzled about how to finish the valves where the toilets and sinks connect. Are you supposed to just leave the plastic visible where the valve is sticking out of the wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the piping (which in your case is pex) will be visible from the wall or floor to your cut off valve. You can put escussion rings on pipe that lay flush against the wall to give it a more finished look.

Comment: thank you, this is the information I was looking for, there's lots of options available: https://www.supplyhouse.com/Escutcheons-for-PEX-856000

Answer (score 1):

The pex usually goes into fittings that are set into the wall.

I used 1/2” elbow fittings well secured for two sinks and a shower. For the shower the fittings had to be on 153mm centres and a bracket was made for that.

Here is a link to the type I used:
https://www.hornbach.ch/shop/Raccord-de-serrage-angle-de-mur-16x2mm-1-2-IG/7011451/article.html

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. Pex is fittings for toilets and sinks in North America look like this https://pexhouse.com/product/dahl-1-2-pex-crimp-f1807-x-3-8-od-comp-angle-stop/. They get their support from the pipe itself, similar to copper.

Comment: In point of fact, you can get "drop ear elbows" for PEX in North America (I have several, the shower arm is a most obvious application), and they are a perfectly good solution if you want a rigid pipe exposed (this is also common with copper piping.) That is indeed one way to "finish" these valves.

Comment: @Ecnerwal all the drop ears I see for sale are expansion PEX to female threaded? How does this let me finish with a expansion PEX valve like the one I link in my first comment?